# In Family Guy, who voiced GRR Martin?

Tags: family-guy

In the Family Guy episode "Pilling them Softly", Brian and Stewie go to a book fair where they meet George RR Martin. Who voiced the character? Was it Martin himself, or a different voice actor?

Comment: I'm not putting this as an answer because I don't know for sure, but I know positively it was *not* Martin himself.  It's hard to say who it was exactly, and I can't find any specific reference to Martin's character, but here's a list of "[The Usual Suspects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Family_Guy_cast_members)".

Comment: Even IMDB does not list [voice credits for characters](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4848902/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm) other than the main characters. If you can DVR it, maybe pause during the end credits and see if it is listed there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There is no indication that it was the real George R. R. Martin**

I have searched all of the relevant resources:

- [Wikia Page for that episode](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Pilling_Them_Softly)
- [Wikia Page for the GRRM character](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/George_R._R._Martin)
- [Wikipedia page for that episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilling_Them_Softly)
- [George R. R. Martin's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_R._R._Martin)

The only indication we get is from [this IGN episode review](http://au.ign.com/articles/2015/09/28/family-guy-pilling-them-softly-review), clearly stating that it is *not* GRRM's voice:

> That dovetailed into subplot involving the two traveling to Hartford to pitch legendary fantasy novelist George R.R. Martin (not voiced by the actual Martin) on Brian's epic medieval space saga.

Now my belief is that Peter's voice is very similar to GRRM's to begin with, so I'm assuming [**Seth**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seth_MacFarlane) did it himself.

Comment: I found the same in my search yesterday. No specific info on who it is but specific info that it is not Martin himself.

Answer (score -1):

It was very difficult to find, but after a lot of searching on **IMDB**, I have found that the animation of *George RR Martin* was voiced by  *Seth Macfarlane*.

Comment: Could you add a source, a link to that claim?

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4848902/

Comment: Where does it say Seth was Martin?